# Akka streams: Bidirectional flow that completes the stage when one side is completed

Tags: scala, akka

This is meant to be a bidirectional flow [BidiFlow](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.4/?_ga=1.56357867.1599112787.1453752722#akka.stream.scaladsl.BidiFlow) that works exactly as `BidiFlow.identity`, except that it completes the stage as soon as one of the Flows (in1 -> out1 or in2 -> out2) is completed.

This can be useful to automatically close a connection fully when one of the two sides is closed.

There are a few tricks to prevent object allocation.

```
import akka.stream.{ Outlet, Inlet, Attributes, BidiShape }
import akka.stream.stage._

object DisconnectBidiFlow {

  def apply[A, B]: GraphStage[BidiShape[A, A, B, B]] = Impl.asInstanceOf[GraphStage[BidiShape[A, A, B, B]]]

  private object Impl extends GraphStage[BidiShape[Any, Any, Any, Any]] {

    val in1: Inlet[Any] = Inlet("DisconnectBidiFlow.in1")
    val out1: Outlet[Any] = Outlet("DisconnectBidiFlow.out1")
    val in2: Inlet[Any] = Inlet("DisconnectBidiFlow.in2")
    val out2: Outlet[Any] = Outlet("DisconnectBidiFlow.out2")

    override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      def map[T](in: Inlet[T], out: Outlet[T]) = {
        val handler = new InHandler with OutHandler {
          override def onPush(): Unit =
            push(out, grab(in))

          override def onPull(): Unit =
            pull(in)
        }
        setHandler(in, handler)
        setHandler(out, handler)
      }
      map(in1, out1)
      map(in2, out2)
    }

    override def shape = BidiShape(in1, out1, in2, out2)
  }
}
```

Questions:

- Can/should the shape be a val
- Suggestions for a better name.

  - It is not really a `BidiFlow` but just shaped like one. It is a `GraphStage[BidiShape[A, A, B, B]]`
  - Should the name contain the purpose (FullDisconnectBidiFlow?)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe talk a bit about the "tricks to prevent object allocation."

Based on the current examples in the Akka docs, the shape should be `override val`. My understanding is that the accepted pattern when designing traits is to `def` your contract, and implement with `val` wherever possible.

As they say - naming is hard and often a matter of taste. The pattern reminds me of a fuse, or breaker - but `fuse` has a particular meaning in Akka, so that's probably not a great choice. Maybe `BreakerFlow`?